# Detecting Image Size Effectively

Tags: javascript, php, image, function, download

What is the best way to check for Image size without downloading it fully to the server.

- Is there a header we can read?
- Is there a way to check if the stream is more than eg 5000 Size(Estimated as big image) Stop stream.

I just want a way to remove small images , and icons.

The Image is a Link, online

I can definitely download everything and check one by one but it seems inefficient

```
getimagesizefromstring
```

See the docs: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getimagesizefromstring.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with php, you can get the headers of a image and then check the size of the Content-Length variable like so:

```
function getSize($url) {
    $head = get_headers($url, 1);
    $len = $head['Content-Length'];
    if (!empty($len)) {
        return $len;
    } else {
        //must download it
    }
}
```

The problem is sometimes the server wont reply with a content length so you cant really calculate it with this method then.

Edit: Re-reading the question I guess I don't know if you mean the image size in pixels or the actual data size, but this method works for the data size.

Answer (score 3):

Since

> What is the best way to check for Image size without me downloading it
>   fully into server.

Make use of the JavaScript **`Image`** Object.

```
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {
      alert ('The image size is '+newImg.width+'*'+newImg.height);
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc;
}
```